# git commitizen does not work after installation

Tags: git, commitizen

I have a problem with `git cz`. I installed it following *Conventional commit messages as a global utility
 * and then when I hit `git cz` everything works but wen I reopen my terminal and hit again `git cz` the comes up

```
`git: 'cz' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`
```

### .profile

> ```
> # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
> # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
> # exists.
> # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
> # the files are located in the bash-doc package.
>
> # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
> # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
> #umask 022
>
> # if running bash
> if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
>     # include .bashrc if it exists
>     if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
>   . "$HOME/.bashrc"
>     fi
> fi
>
> # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
> if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
>     PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
> fi
>
> # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
> if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
>     PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
> fi
> ```